# Separate data from multiple rows in picker view

Tags: view, row, rows, picker

I created picker view with 4 rows, but data in all rows are same. So how could i separate data from each row and use it for calculating?

Comment: Maybe add iOS / UIKit tag would help.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps this may work for your problem of not displaying the data? Can't really tell because I can't see what you've already done.

```
-(NSInteger)numberOfComponentsInPickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView{
    return 4;
}
-(NSInteger)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView numberOfRowsInComponent (NSInteger)component{

    return rowOneItems.count;
    return rowTwoItems.count;
    return rowThreeItems.count;
    return rowFourItems.count;
}
-(NSString*)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView titleForRow:(NSInteger)row forComponent:(NSInteger)component{

    if(component == 1)
        return[rowTwoItems objectAtIndex:row];
    else if(component == 2)
        return[rowThreeItems objectAtIndex:row];
    else if(component == 3)
        return[rowFourItems objectAtIndex:row];
    else
        return [rowOneItems objectAtIndex:row];
}
```